# Dynamically created DOM element not increasing div size

Tags: jquery, css, html, dynamic

I have a selection drop down, which dynamically changes based on the first selection. 
I also have the option to add more selections and this creates more drop down select boxes dynamically.

However, i want the new drop downs to increase the height of the div that they sit in (and so push any content below it down), but at the moment the new drop downs just seem to sit on top of any content in the div below. I think it may have to do with the nesting of the divs, but would appreciate some help.

Here is my structure:

```
<div class="pageMiddle">
<div id="tutor_profile_container">
     <div id="profile_pic">
    <div class="subjselect"> 
        <h3>Primary  Subject</h3>
    <div class="select">
        <select id="subject">
        <option value="">Subject</option>
        <option value="other subjects">other subjests</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id='topic' class='select'>
        <select id="topic">
        <option value="">Topic</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="another" class="more" onclick="Repeat(this)">Add Another Subject</a>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
           <div id="tutor_profile">
            some form content
    </div>
   </div> 
    <hr>
```

and the JQuery:

```
function Repeat(obj) {
    var currentDiv = $(obj).parents('.subjselect');
    console.log(currentDiv)
    var dropDown = currentDiv.find('select');
    console.log(dropDown);
    dropDown.addClass("select");
    dropDown.clone().appendTo('#another');
}
$(function () {
    $("select#subject").change(function () {
        var subject = $("select#subject>option:selected").text();
        console.log(subject);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'tutorprofileinput.php',
            data: {
                "subject": subject
            },
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var options = [];

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    counts = Object.keys(data).length;
                    console.log(counts);
                    options += '<option value="' + val.topic + '">' + val.topic + '</option>';
                    console.log(options);
                });
                $("select#topic").html(options);
            },
            error: function () {
                // failed request; give feedback to user
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
            }
        });
    })
})
```

and the CSS:

```
#pageMiddle{
    width:940px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    position:relative;
}

#tutor_profile_container{
}

#profile_pic{
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    float:left; 
    width:282px;
    top:7px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    height:90%;
}

#tutor_profile{
    position:relative;
    left:305;
    width:612;
    border: 2px dashed yellow;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.select { 
    margin: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('../images/new_arrow.jpg');
    background-position: right center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.select select{
   background: transparent;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 33px;
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
   color:#6F6F78;
   z-index: 3000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not due to nesting divs it is due to `position:absolute`. The `div` and it's wrappers etc etc should have a `position:relative`

Comment: but when i change the position attribute of #profile_pic then the content in #tutor_profile is pushed way down, which I dont want - i want to have two columns side by side, but that increase in height with additional content

Comment: have two columns by floating one of them within a wrapper div. Don't use `position:absolute` for that purpose. All the time you have it set to `positiob:absolute` it will never increase. The alternative is a complex ajax javascript function to dynamically adjust the height.

Comment: ok vector - thanks for this help - got it working with position:relative